# Way to show not normalized data in LIME

Tags: artificial-intelligence, visualization, normalization, lime

Is there any way to show the true/natural value in lime package after rescaling the data? I have used rescaling for the logistic regression algorithm, now when I want to display the prediction, it is showing scaled values. I could not use non-scaled values for logistic regression. So I need a way to show natural data for the lime visualization.

[image]